# grab each tr value and make a object with td values

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please check the code bellow. On `#btnConfirm` button click i have to grab each `class="invTr" data-productid="1"` then inside each of those `tr` i have to grab two `td` text which is- `Quantity` and `Price Per Unit` then make a store whole object in `var Items = {}`. In jquery code comments you will get a sample of object output i wanted to be. Anyone can make output like this from my current `tr`? The code i already have tried is like jquery bellow but i am stuck on here with error says `push of undefined`. Any idea to make output like this? Also anyone if can provide JSON object output that also great. Thanks in advance

Currently error i am getting is:

> Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Here is my [js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7510pnLo/) for quick try

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-hover table-sm">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Title</th>
            <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
            <th scope="col">Price Per Unit</th>
            <th scope="col">Total Price</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="invTr" data-productid="1"> <td>lavenda things</td> <td> <input type="number" class="form-control qty" style="width:75px;" pattern="[0-9]" min="1" max="10000" value="1"> </td> <td> 10.00 </td> <td> 20.55 </td> <td>pp</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr class="invTr" data-productid="2"> <td>lavenda things</td> <td> <input type="number" class="form-control qty" style="width:75px;" pattern="[0-9]" min="1" max="10000" value="3"> </td> <td> 20.00 </td> <td> 20.55 </td> <td>pp</td> 
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="btnConfirm">Confirm</button>
```

Jquery:

```
//confirm button on click actions
$('#btnConfirm').on('click', function () {



  var Items = {};
  var invTrClassesObj = {};
  var _invTrClasses = $('.invTr');
  $.each(_invTrClasses, function (i, invTrClasse) {
    invTrClassesObj.ProductId.push(invTrClasse.attr('data-productId'));
  }); 


  //console.log(Items); //I want output object like this-> { ProductId:1 { Price:10.00, Quantiry:1 }, ProductId:2 { Price:20.00, Quantiry:3 } }

});
```

Comment: Hi, it looks like `invTrClassesObj` doesn't have the key value `ProductId`.

Comment: Ok but check the jquery comments where i have given my object output in final. Can you make output like this?

Comment: Also, your `invTrClasse.attr` section is incorrect, since `attr()` is part of `jQuery`, while your invTrClasses, is standard `javascript` (html output). So, you will also need to do `$(invTrClasse).attr`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`invTrClassesObj.ProductId` gives `'push' of undefined` becasuse of `invTrClassesObj.ProductId` is not set yet.

I have added code to get your required JSON object output.

```js
//confirm button on click actions
$('#btnConfirm').on('click', function () {

var x = document.querySelectorAll(".invTr");

//console.log(x);
  var Items = {};
  var invTrClassesObj = [];
  var _invTrClasses = $('.invTr');
  $.each(_invTrClasses, function (i, invTrClasse) {
    invTrClassesObj.push(
    {
      'ProductId':invTrClasse.getAttribute('data-productId'),
      'Price': $(this).find("td").eq(2).html(),
      'Quantiry':$(this).closest('tr').find(".qty").val()
      });
  }); 
  
console.log(invTrClassesObj);

  //console.log(Items); //I want output object like this-> { ProductId:1 { Price:10.00, Quantiry:1 }, ProductId:2 { Price:20.00, Quantiry:3 } }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-hover table-sm">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Title</th>
            <th scope="col">Quantity</th>
            <th scope="col">Price Per Unit</th>
            <th scope="col">Total Price</th>
            <th scope="col">Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr class="invTr" data-productid="1"> <td>lavenda things</td> <td> <input type="number" class="form-control qty" style="width:75px;" pattern="[0-9]" min="1" max="10000" value="1"> </td> <td> 10.00 </td> <td> 20.55 </td> <td>pp</td> 
    </tr>
    <tr class="invTr" data-productid="2"> <td>lavenda things</td> <td> <input type="number" class="form-control qty" style="width:75px;" pattern="[0-9]" min="1" max="10000" value="3"> </td> <td> 20.00 </td> <td> 20.55 </td> <td>pp</td> 
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<button id="btnConfirm">Confirm</button>
```